# Why do Metabox use Nonces?

Tags: metabox, wp-admin, security, nonce

Why is it advised for admin panel metaboxes to use nonces? Every example I see of creation and saving metabox data there are nonces involved but aren't nonces a bit unnecessary in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WordPress nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Nonce) are meant to prevent unauthorized execution of code.  In the case of meta boxes, they are protecting you against malicious users potentially adding unauthorized meta-information to your posts and pages by forging POST requests.  Why *wouldn't* you want to use nonces?

Comment: Idk, I've just started reading into nonces, but if a user is already logged into the admin panel as an admin anyway then nonces or not they would still be able to execute code in the metabox.

Comment: Nonces are roughly defined [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Nonce), but the definition lacks information.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes, but nonces are meant to prevent an attacker from sending arbitrary `POST` data to, say, http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=5&action=edit and having WordPress merrily execute it.  (Or are you arguing that there's already a nonce on that page for the `post_content`, so why the second one?  I'm not sure of the answer to that.)